# use xslt to change only a few XML elements while leaving everything else the same

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following problem with XSLT.

In an XML document I have several `<h></h>` tags embedded within different levels of `<div></div>` tags.

In effort to change all the `<h></h>` to `<h1></h1>` `<h2></h2>` `<h3></h3>` respective to where the fall within the different div sections I have written the following XSLT script.

```
<xsl:template match="//TU:div/TU:h">
    <h1><xsl:apply-templates/></h1>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="//TU:div/TU:div/TU:h">
    <h2><xsl:apply-templates/></h2>
</xsl:template>
```

And so on. . . .
The problem is that I want everything else to stay exactly the same. I only want the `<h></h>` tags to change.

Unfortunately, when I process the document, the `<h></h>` tags change as desired, but all other elements go away.

Is there another solution to this problem besides simply writing an `<xsl:template>` for each element, so that every given element will be replaced with itself?

For example for the element `<p></p>`:

```
<xsl:template match="//TU:p">
    <p><xsl:apply-template/></p>
</xsl:template>
```

Do I need to do something like that to preserve each element, or is there a better way?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you post a sample XML input file?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add the identity template to match everything else...

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="TU:h">
  <xsl:variable name="id" select="count(ancestor::TU:div)" />
  <xsl:element name="h{$id}" namespace="TUSTEP">
     <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" />
  </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You could also put extra checks in to limit id to a max value if you want

Comment: Thanks Bob -- this works nicely, though I did need to change `TU:h{$id}` to `h{$id}' because it was changing things to `<TU:h1>` instead of '<h1>'. Also can you explain why I'm getting the following attribute after in each `<h>` element: `<h1 xmlns="">` I'd like this to go away. Any ideas.

Comment: Yes, sorry its a namespacing issue you need to fill in the namespace attribute on xsl:element to the same value as what the namespace TU maps to, if can supply the namespace  string I can update the answer

Comment: Hi Bob, the namespace I'm using is declared in the root element as `<TUSTEP xmlns="TUSTEP">` Let me know if you have a suggestion. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try a generic template like this:

```
<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Yes, but this will unfortunately discard attributes. See Bob's identity template (the standard version).